# Referring to session variables (\set var='value') from PL/PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, scope, plpgsql, psql

I can pass variables into PostgreSQL using

```
psql --variable="var='value'" <<<'SELECT :var'
```

...and refer to them as, in this case, `:var` in SQL queries passed to psql on stdin.

However, this doesn't work from code using PL/PGSQL:

```
psql --variable=var="'value'" <<'EOF'
  DO $$
  BEGIN
    SELECT :var;
  END;
  $$
EOF
```

...yielding the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot to use a psql variables inside plpgsql code directly. The symbol substitution is blocked inside strings:

```
postgres=> select :'xx';
 ?column? 
----------
 AHOJ
(1 row)

postgres=> select ' :xx ';
?column? 
----------
 :xx 
(1 row)
```

But you can set a server session variables and later to use this kind of variables in plpgsql code (on server side):

```
postgres=> set myvars.xx = :'xx';
SET
postgres=> do $$ begin 
                   raise notice '>>%<<', current_setting('myvars.xx');
                 end $$;
NOTICE:  >>AHOJ<<
DO
```

You can use same technique from command line, see: http://okbob.blogspot.cz/2015/01/how-to-push-parameters-to-do-statement.html

last note - the code

```
BEGIN
  SELECT some;
END;
```

is invalid in plpgsql. Results of any `SELECT`s should be stored in some variables. Postgres has not possibility to returns result of free `SELECT` to client - `DO` statement is not equivalent of MS SQL procedure.